# Check or Validate that a form entry begins with a certain letter

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I've tried many different fixes for this but evidently I'm not getting it just right!  I need javascript to validate that `emp_id` entered by the user starts with an S or s.

Company information tells me to do this:

```
 if (document.User.FirstName.value != "" & document.User.LastName.value != "" & document.User.EmpID.value != "" & (/^S/.test(document.User.EmpID.value))) 

 else 
      {
         alert("You must enter your name and Student ID.  Student ID must begin with an S plus seven digits, before your completion can be recorded.");
```

The form entry is:

```
<p align="center">Student ID: <input TYPE="text" id="emp_id" NAME="emp_id" SIZE="8" MAXLENGTH="8">
```

I have also tried

```
if (document.User.FirstName.value != "" & document.User.LastName.value != "" & document.User.emp_id.value != "" & (/^[S]/.test(document.User.EmpID.value)))
```

along with a few other variations, but so far, no luck.

I can't deviate too much from this text (like adding a different type of function or validation).  Is it possible to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

First, `&` by itself does not indicate AND, you need `&&`.

Second, you could easily update your regex in the second conditional statement to `^[Ss]` to catch upper `S` and lower case `s`.

Third, It seems you are accessing a document element that does not exist. It would seem that you need `emp_id` and NOT `EmpID`.

EDIT(Thanks to @RobG): You can also add the `i` flag to indicate that case is not considered in the expression. For your first if statement `/^S/i.test(document.User.EmpID.value)`

Due to new comments:

`if (document.User.FirstName.value != "" && document.User.LastName.value != "" && document.User.emp_id.value != "" && /^S/i.test(document.User.emp_id.value))` should work, I have tested generally and it seems to be working(with strings that begin with the letter S. If the string does not begin with the letter `s` or `S` then the regex fails.

Comment: Or add the `i` flag to save one character. :-)

Comment: Thank you @bwtrent. Unfortunately still not working.  I now have:if (document.User.FirstName.value != "" & document.User.LastName.value != "" & document.User.emp_id.value != "" && (/^[Ss]/.test(document.User.EmpID.value)))

Comment: ALL those single ampersands need to be doubled there should not be a solitary ampersand in your conditional statement.

Comment: Good to know, thanks.  BUT everything else that has only the one & is currently working.  Just not this part.

Comment: @user1314071 You may also want to add `.toString()` to the end of the value accesser and make sure you're requesting the right thing. `emp_id` vs `EmpID` I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @bwtrent!  I noticed that the emp_id wasn't correct last night. I corrected it but it's still not even stopping to check for the S, it just goes straight to checking that the dropdown menu has been chosen.

Comment: I'm not sure how to mark the code correctly here, (sorry, such a newb) but it's checking all these things accurately but skipping over the part with S check:

Comment: if (Check == 15) {
      if (document.User.FirstName.value != "" && document.User.LastName.value != "" && document.User.emp_id.value != "" & (/^S/i.test(document.User.emp_id.value))) 
      {
         if (UserCampus != "Select Campus - Click Here") 
         {
//added the following two lines
         if (document.User.confirm_policy.checked)
         {

Comment: @user1314071 I have tested with strings that begin with `S`||`s` and the regex is sound. It is not skipping the regex. It would seem that the string is passing the regex test.

Comment: Again, very new to this...is there an obvious way to keep it from passing the regex?  I am on deadline and completely unsure what to do! Thanks for all your help @bwtrent, it's appreciated.

Comment: @user1314071, we are now at the point of finding out what strings you are passing to it that should fail. (you can change the numbers so that it does not match any personal information).